# how use checkBox is Checked change textcolor

Tags: jquery, css

I wanted Inputype is ***Checked*** . Text Color is ***RED***.

```
 <div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox"> Sedan <span>(10)</span></label></div>
 <div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox"> Sedan <span>(10)</span></label></div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kisspa/6Qa39/1/)

Comment: `I wanted pureCss not use Jquery and javascript.` Then why did you tag this question with jquery..?  :0

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6Qa39/11/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your html like this :-

```
<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"/> <label>Sedan <span>(10)</span></label></div>
```

and then in css:-

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
color: red;  
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zqJU7/)

Comment: hey friends. you answer is good but checkBox is within label what i want.

Comment: please! you see my fiddle.

Comment: @theinlwin hi you can't do it by css you have to change html or you can use jquery instread.

Answer (score 1):

Try use the below code

But this will work from IE9 + browser

```
<div class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox"> 
<label>Sedan <span>(10)</span></label>
</div>
```

and in css

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
color: #f00;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: hey friends. i wanted within label

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Qa39/6/).

What I did: fixed your css selector and html label tags.

changed html to

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <label> Sedan <span>(10)</span></label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <label> Sedan <span>(10)</span></label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <label> Sedan <span>(10)</span></label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <label> Sedan <span>(10)</span></label>
</div>
```

and css to

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label{
    color:red;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + span{
    color:red;
}
```